# Sorting data in .json.jbuilder file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

users_controller.eb

```
def index
 users=User.all
end
```

index.json.jbuilder

```
json.users_availability @users.order('name ASC') do |user|
  json.(user, :id, :name)
end
```

I want to sort users alphabetically so I tried *.order('name ASC')* but it doesn't work. Please help me find where I am going wrong.

Then I tried

*@users.sort_by(&:name)* it works but it is not case insensitive. It sorts the users as below.

```
Abby
James
William
bob
jack
rob
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort case insensitively you can do this.

```
@users.order("lower(name)")
```

or in Ruby

```
@users.sort_by! { |u| u.name.downcase }
```